# How Can i use multiple lists using partial view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I have used this code for my controller side

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult IndexBlog()
        {
            List<Blog> blogs;
            blogs = db.Blogs.Where(x => x.Is_Active.Equals(true)).ToList();
            return View(blogs);
        }
```

and for view i have used this one

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectLastSupper.Models.Blog>

@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div>
            <div class="box_@Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.blog_Id) ">
                <div class="pic ">
                    <h2 class="flt ">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Blog_Watermark)</h2>
                    <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.Blog_Image_Path)" alt="~/assets/Images/clg_4.jpg" class="short ">
                </div>
                <div class="cont ">
                    <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.Blog_Name)</h3>
                    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.Blog_Description)</p>
                    <a class="button" href="@Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.Blog_URL)">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

although there is data in corresponding database it detects model as null. can any one help what is wrong here? I am new to C# and MVC I didn't find any solve for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var blogs = db.Blogs.Where(x => x.Is_Active).ToList();
 return View(blogs);
```

and this

```
@if (Model != null)
{
   @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i+=1)
  {
    {
        <div>
            <div class="box_@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model[i].blog_Id) ">
                <div class="pic ">
                    <h2 class="flt ">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Blog_Watermark)</h2>
                    <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model[i].Blog_Image_Path)" alt="~/assets/Images/clg_4.jpg" class="short ">
                </div>
                <div class="cont ">
                    <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Blog_Name)</h3>
                    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Blog_Description)</p>
                    <a class="button" href="@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model[i].Blog_URL)">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```